# Binary training result in chainer

Tags: cnn, accuracy, mnist

I am training simple Chainer based CNN to recognise MNIST samples. To each sample I add poissonian noise. For the test purpose I have always the same random seed. I restart training resetting the model for each new poisson mean.

I would expect that with increasing the mean of the poisson noise, the accuracy of the CNN should drop. Instead the behaviour is different. Indeed, when increasing the mean, the CNN takes longer and longer to train. But it either suceeds and usually gets to the target accuracy of 9X% regardless of the poisson mean, or does not train at all, staying at accuracy of ~10%. The higher the poisson mean, the bigger the probability that it will not train successfully and stay at the 10%. Could someone help me understand this behaviour?

[image]